# Cassandra script to change date to Instant type

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to change all data values in cassandra
from: `2020-05-18T14:18:45.878Z`
to `1593402243336` (like Instant Java type)

all data in this column are of type `text`

I wonder how to write a script that changes dates from for example `2020-05-18T14:18:45.878Z` to `1593402243336`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra, there is a separate `timestamp` type to keep such information.  Internally, it stores the data as 8-byte long value representing time in milliseconds.  This value is accessed via driver, and could be transformed into the value of type specific to the programming languages used.  If you're accessing these values via `cqlsh` you will need them printed as `2020-05-18T14:18:45.878Z`, but in reality it's the still `long` type under the hood.

To perform such conversion you need 2 things:

1. You need to add another column with `timestamp` type - you can't change type of the existing column
2. You need to use some tool to perform such conversion, but this is really depends on your requirements.  You can do it, for example:

- Spark - just do something like this using the [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

```scala
val data = { spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> "", "keyspace" -> ""))
    .load().withColumnRenamed("text_column", "date_column")}
data.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
   .options(Map("table" -> "", "keyspace" -> "")).mode("append").save()
```

- [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html). You can unload data from your database onto the disk, and then load back, but use timestamp column instead of the text column by providing the custom mapping with `-m` option.  There is a serie of blog posts about DSBulk, that could provide more information & examples: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Comment: Can I use Spark Cassandra in my Spring boot app to run my app to update date format from 2020-05-18T14:18:45.878Z to 1593402243336 (Instant epochMilli)?

Comment: not the easiest way to do it... As I understand, you need to do one time conversion?

Comment: yes, one time conversion to change format of old data..And I wonder how and where to do it the easiest way

Comment: Just run it outside of the any application... I think that integration with Spring Boot could be more complex compared to it

Comment: How can I run the code like your example above? Can I run it somehow in my Intellij Ultimate where I'm connected to my Cassandra (from the SQL console)?

Comment: I don't know about Intellij, you can download Spark and run that commands