# DataStax Bulk Loader - to change date format in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Does anyone know this tool (DataStax Bulk Loader)? I'd like to change date format in some rows from  `2020-05-18T14:18:45.878Z` to `1593402243336` (like Instant Java type/epochMilliseconds) because of the error in code.

The date in this "column" in cassandra is of type `text`. Is it possible? I tried to create a proper script but without any success

Answer (score 1):

No, all available options for time/date conversion are applied to the columns with `time`, `date`, or `timestamp` types.  As I suggested in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711959/cassandra-script-to-change-date-to-instant-type/62713007#62713007), you need to create a column with `timestamp` type, unload from the `text` column, and load into the new column, and then unload into milliseconds format if it's necessary...

P.S. Although, can you add more information why you need so complex approach?